# How to get full URL from WebBrowser?

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys I am using a webrower to get an access token to a website. The website redirects the webrower to a url containing the access token the redirected url looks like this:

http://www.myurl.us/#access_token=e0a81edc8de4886b7cc514bcb2b93e06666bd0d8&expires_in=3600&token_type=bearer&refresh_token=72e302438349b32a627b12c92b01060169443a9b&account_username=

in the DocumentCompleted event for my webrowser I am using this code:

```
Dim pretoken As String
    Dim url As String = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString
    If url.Contains("myurl.us") Then
        pretoken = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString
        MessageBox.Show(pretoken)
    End If
```

The message box only shows "myurl.us" and not the full url with the token i need.  Anyway to get the whole url from the webbrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString()`, like:

```
  Dim url As String = WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString()
```

Be careful with `AbsoluteUri` it's not `AbsoluteUrl`

Comment: Hey thanks tried that still didnt work.  I still am getting redirected to myurl.us instead of myurl.us/#access_token=... etc. I know its a prblem with the webbrowser because it works fine in chrome. Could it be that webbrowser is stripping out everything after the #?

Comment: Try to browse directly from a browser and it will automatically redirect you to `myurl.us/?nr=0` so more like webserver automatically redirecting you to `myurl.us/?nr=0` link. I tried the `DocumentCompleted` event and it shows the original full path URL with # that you posted in my case.

Comment: Good to know that it worked for you @ZachJohnson. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sPagePath As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```